# How to hide and show a label and its field prior to and after a selection from a selection list

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am creating a form which allows a customer to input his order details. The payment method in the selection list has 3 options. If the option selected is credit or debit card then the user will have to input the card number. My problem is I want the card number label and its field to be hidden until the user makes the selection. Can anybody please tell me how to do this?

Comment: Hi and welcome. Please google for "js select onchange" and "css display hidden block". Try to find a way to implement this, if you get into an error or get stuck come back. There are so many tutorials out there that show how to do such things.

Comment: Or this-> http://goo.gl/RWS8FV

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<scirpt src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('input').keypress(function() {
        $('input').css('visibility','visible');
    })
});
</script>

<body>
<form>
    <input type="text" name="credit-card" placeholder='####-####-####-####'>
    <input type="text" style="visibility:hidden;" name="name-on-card">
    <input type="date" style="visibility:hidden;" name="date-on-card">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working sippet with a basic example:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('select').on('change',function(){
    var val = $(this).val();
    DisplayField(val);
  })
  function DisplayField(val){
    if(val === '1')
      {
        $('#credit').show();
        $('#debit').hide();
      }else if(val === '2'){
        $('#debit').show();
        $('#credit').hide();
      }else{
        $('#credit, #debit').hide();
      }
  }
});
```

```css
#credit, #debit{display:none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
  <option value="0">Select Payment Method</option>
  <option value="1">Credit Card</option>
  <option value="2">Debit Card</option>
</select>

<div id="credit">Credit Card Number <input type="text" /></div>
<div id="debit">Debit Card Number <input type="text" /></div>
```